How can I change col/row behavior based on available space?
I have a set of cards, whose have their own cards, like this (i am using TailwindCSS btw):


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-4 border">
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 1</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 2</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-4 border">
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 4</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 5</div>
  </div>
</div>



The end result will be something like this, which is fine:
a image showing the rendered result of the cards
But depending on screen size, i can get a result like this:
a image showing the rendered result of the cards with a gap on the second card
So, what i want to do is that, when there is room available, the "mini cards" act like rows instead of columns, like this (but dynamic):
a image showing the rendered result of the cards without a gap on the second card


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-4 border">
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 1</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 2</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-wrap flex-col justify-between gap-4 border">
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 4</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 5</div>
  </div>
</div>



Is there a way to achieve this with CSS?

You can try to force .flex-grow a min-width if among a group of flex box that has 3 children and a box less than 3  : .grid:has(.flex-grow:nth-child(3)) .flex:not(.flex-col,:has(:nth-child(3))) .flex-grow {min-width:100%;} That's average, it is not testing  if there is a mix of boxes with different amount of rows. You may take a look at container queries to check boxe's height

You could use Flexbox for the outer container instead of Grid or use a responsive utility variant.  However, there is still a portion of width where the unwanted behavior remains.


hr {margin-block: 2em !important}
p {margin-block-end: 1em !important}
<p>Flexbox instead of Grid. Use class "basis-1/3" to emulate three columns.</p>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex gap-4">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-4 border basis-1/3">
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 1</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 2</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-4 border basis-1/3">
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 4</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 5</div>
  </div>
</div>


<hr>


<p>Responsive with small breakpoint. Uses classes "basis-full sm:basis-auto"</p>

<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-4 border">
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 1</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 2</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-between gap-4 border">
    <div class="flex-grow basis-full sm:basis-auto">Content 4</div>
    <div class="flex-grow">Content 5</div>
  </div>
</div>



